# Python logging: unicode symbols is unicode-escaped

Tags: python

I want to log requests responses to file, but when i use `getLogger().warning(string)`, following string is being unicode-escaped
Example:

```
r = requests.post(...)
result = json.loads(r.text)  # Now result == '{"error": "Ошибка 1"}'
getLogger().warning(json.dumps(result))
```

This code will write to log file unicode-escaped string, where "Ошибка" will be written like "\u0417\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437..."
But i want to see these characters as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `json.dumps` is converting the Unicode to ASCII by escaping it. This can be avoided by adding an extra parameter, `ensure_ascii=False`, to the `.dumps` function:

```
r = requests.post(...)
result = json.loads(r.text)  # Now result == {"error": "Ошибка 1"}
getLogger().warning(json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False))
```

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) for other arguments to the json.dumps function.